# Admin Form is displaying on left Tab section in Magento CE 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminform, magento-1.9.2.0

Which i am creating form to save data in table but it is displaying it in left side in tab section in my custom module,

[image]

Grid Container

**Block/Adminhtml/Grid.php**

```
class Custom_Abc_Block_Adminhtml_Customize extends  Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
/**
 * constructor
 *
 * @access public
 * @return void
 * @author Custom
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->_controller         = 'adminhtml_abc_customize_customize';
    $this->_blockGroup         = 'custom_abc';

    $this->_headerText         = Mage::helper('custom_abc')->__('Custom Abc');
    $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper("custom_abc")->__("Add Custom Abc");

    parent::__construct();
}
}
```

**Block/Adminhtml/Customize/Edit.php**

```
class Custom_Abc_Block_Adminhtml_Customize_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_objectId = 'id';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'custom_abc';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_abc_customize_customize';
    $this->_updateButton(
        'save',
        'label',
        Mage::helper('custom_abc')->__('Save Custom')
    );
    $this->_updateButton(
        'delete',
        'label',
        Mage::helper('custom_abc')->__('Delete Custom')
    );
    $this->_addButton(
        'saveandcontinue',
        array(
            'label'   => Mage::helper('custom_abc')->__('Save And Continue Edit'),
            'onclick' => 'saveAndContinueEdit()',
            'class'   => 'save',
        ),
        -100
    );
    $this->_formScripts[] = "
        function saveAndContinueEdit() {
            editForm.submit($('edit_form').action+'back/edit/');
        }
    ";
}

public function getHeaderText()
{
    if (Mage::registry('current_custom') && Mage::registry('current_custom')->getId()) {
        return Mage::helper('custom_custom')->__(
            "Edit Custom '%s'",
            $this->escapeHtml(Mage::registry('current_custom')->getTin())
        );
    } else {
        return Mage::helper('custom_abc')->__('Add Custom');
    }
}
}
```

**Block/Adminhtml/Customize/Edit/tabs.php**

```
class Custom_Abc_Block_Adminhtml_Customize_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('custom_info_tabs');
    $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
    $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('custom_abc')->__('Custom Information'));
}

protected function _beforeToHtml() {
    $this->addTab("form_section", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("custom_abc")->__("Custom Abc Information"),
        "title" => Mage::helper("custom_abc")->__("Custom Abc Information"),
        "content" => $this->getLayout()->createBlock("custom_abc/adminhtml_customize_edit_tab_form")->toHtml(),
    ));
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}

}
```

**Block/Adminhtml/Customize/Edit/form.php**

```
class Custom_Abc_Block_Adminhtml_Customize_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

protected function _prepareForm() {
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        "id" => "edit_form",
        "action" => $this->getUrl("adminhtml/abc_customize_customize/save", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))),
        "method" => "post",
        "enctype" => "multipart/form-data",
            )
    );
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

}
```

**Block/Adminhtml/Customize/Edit/Tab/form.php**

```
class Custom_Abc_Block_Adminhtml_Customize_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

protected function _prepareForm() {

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $this->setForm($form);
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset("custom_form", array("legend" => Mage::helper("custom_abc")->__("Add Custom Abc")));

    $fieldset->addField("custom_id", "text", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("custom_abc")->__("Custom Id"),
        "name" => "custom_id",
    ));


    if (Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getCustomData()) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getCustomData());
        Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->setCustomData(null);
    } elseif (Mage::registry("current_Custom")) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry("current_Custom")->getData());
    }
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}

}
```

**controllers/Adminhtml/Abc/Customize/CustomizeController.php**

```
class Custom_Abc_Adminhtml_Abc_Customize_CustomizeController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

public function indexAction() {

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function newAction() {

    $this->_title($this->__("Custom"));
    $this->_title($this->__("Custom"));
    $this->_title(  $this->__("New Item"));

    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id");
    $model = Mage::getModel("custom_abc/custom")->load($id);

    $data = Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->getFormData(true);
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $model->setData($data);
    }

    Mage::register("current_custom", $model);

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu("custom_abc/abcd");

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setCanLoadExtJs(true);

    $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Custom Manager"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Custom Manager"));
    $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Custom Description"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Custom Description"));


    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock("custom_abc/adminhtml_customize_edit"))->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock("custom_abc/adminhtml_customize_edit_tabs"));

    $this->renderLayout();
}

}
```

Comment: add controller code too

Comment: sure give me a second sir

Comment: @Qaisar Sir I have added the controller code please check

Comment: check the error log there is any error?

Comment: sir i am getting and exception in exception.log
'Invalid block type: Custom_Abc_Block_Adminhtml_Xyz_Customize_Customize_Edit_Form'

Comment: problem with your `$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_abc_customize_customize';` change to `$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_customize';`

Comment: i traced this problem sir but thank you very much for your help I forgot to enable log just tell me one thing my controller is in controllers/adminhtml/abcd/customize/customizecontroller.php

do i need to keep file like this 
controllers/adminhtml/customizecontroller.php

or with same path i can write like this adminhtml_customize

Comment: no need to change controller path leave it as it is.. just add it adminhtml/yourfoldername

Comment: For me, it was a missed `$this->_blockGroup` sentence in the Edit block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem with your `$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_abc_customize_customize';` change to `$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_customize';`